# Как можно подключать новых юзер ботов с помошь класса

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Кто знает как можно создавать подключать новых юзер ботов с помошью класса
Вот мой код

```
import threading
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client, filters

class Bot():
    def __init__(self, name, tel):
         self.name = name
         self.tel  = tel
         self.api_id = 12345
         self.api_hash = ""

     def create_bot(self):
         code      = input("Введите код: ")
         self.name = Client(self.name, self.api_id, self.api_hash, phone_number=self.tel, phone_code=code)
         self.name.connect()
         return

    async def sign(self):
         await self.name.send_code(self.tel)       
         await self.name.create_bot() 
    def start(self):
         self.name.start()
    def idle(self):
         self.name.idle()

bots = []

ff = input('Что хочешь (Создать аккаунт, Выйти):')

if ff == 'Создать аккаунт':
    bot = Bot('my_bot','+998915243845')
    asyncio.run(bot.sign())
    bot.start()
    bot.idle()
```

но выходит ошибка

> Что хочешь (Создать аккаунт, Выйти):Создать аккаунт Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/home/preiwer/Documents/Our_folder/forwarder/.venv/main/user__bot_class.py",
> line 37, in 
> asyncio.run(bot.sign())   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
> return loop.run_until_complete(main)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in
> run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "/home/preiwer/Documents/Our_folder/forwarder/.venv/main/user__bot_class.py",
> line 24, in sign
> await self.name.send_code(self.tel)        AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_code'. Did you mean: 'encode'?